# Migrating API and DB to a new server

Tags: nginx, ssl, migration

Please bear with me as I am not well-versed in devops.

I have a production server with a database, landing page, and API hosted at a domain - https://a.com and https://api.a.com

I set up a clone of that server and pointed https://b.com and https://api.b.com to it, and everything is working correctly.

Both servers are up on Digital Ocean, and I have A records pointing from https://a.com to the IP of the current production server. I also have A records pointing from https://b.com to the server I want to migrate to. Once I migrate, I understand that there will be some propagation delay, but this is okay as I can serve a notice in the app and block access for anyone who is still hitting the old server.

My plan at this stage would be to:

- Completely set up server B
- Remove b.com's A records
- Serve notice for current users of server A's API
- Switch A records for a.com/api.a.com over to the new server
- Pray

The only problem I have now is that I can't seem to set up the SSL certificates for https://a.com on server B without the correct domain pointing to it. When I use certbot with a.com it fails and I can't figure out why (something about an acme challenge failing in .well-known, but I've scoured the internet and feel I can't figure it out with my current skills).

My questions:

- Is there an easy way to set up SSL certs for a.com on a server only being pointed to by b.com
- Is there a better way to do this than my current approach?

EDIT: I have figured out how to deploy SSL certs using the following command:

certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns -d a.com

This manually guided me to add TXT records to a.com so that it would give me the certs, and it set up 443 on the nginx file too.

Answer (score 1):

You can set certificate with SAN (Subject Alternative Name) where to list all the hostnames: `a.com`, `b.com`, `api.a.com`, `api.b.com` and you can use this certificate on any host name (from the list)

About DNS: you can speedup the propagation of the record by set TTL for old record to one hour (do this several days before the act). Then change the IP, wait hour or two, change back TTL to the default value.